# Let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $0≤a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n<3$. Given $p(\sqrt 3)=20+17\sqrt 3$ find $p(2)$

Tags: polynomials

I tried to make an equation $20+2x+2x^3+x^5$ which satisfied the above property but after putting 2 in place of $x$ I am not getting the correct answer. The answer is 86 but I want to know how or why 86 is true and mine is false.

Comment: How do you know $86$ is correct?

Comment: Bcz I have posted this question from a prestigious book and the answer given is 86

Comment: No restriction on $a_0$ except it is integer?  Then I don't see how the answer could possibly be unique.  Perhaps there's a typo and it should say $0 \le a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n < 3$.

Comment: $$p(\sqrt3)=a_0+a_1(\sqrt3)+a_2(\sqrt3)^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$$

$$p(\sqrt3)=a_0+a_2(3)+a_4(3^2)+\cdots+a_1(\sqrt3)+a_3(\sqrt3)^3+\cdots=20+17\sqrt3$$

$$p(\sqrt3)=(a_0+a_2(3)+a_4(3^2)+\cdots)+\sqrt3(a_1+a_3(3)+\cdots)=20+17\sqrt3$$

Compare both sides;

$$a_0+a_2(3)+a_4(3^2)+\cdots=20$$

$$a_1+a_3(3)+\cdots=17$$

You should be getting $p(x)=2+2x+2x^3+2x^4+x^5$ and $p(2)=86$

Comment: @ayan In base $3$, we have $17_{10}=122_3$, so $a_1=2, a_3=2, a_5=1$ are fixed.  However we cannot similarly say $20_{10}=202_3$ as $a_0$ is not restricted to be $<3$.  For e.g. as the OP noted, $a_0=20, a_{2k}=0$ for $k>0$ works perfectly.    Similarly $a_0=3m+2$ works for any non-negative integer $m\leqslant 6$, the remainder is a multiple of $3$ which has a base $3$ representation which will fit for remaining $a_{2k}$. e.g. with $m=4$, we have $a_0=14, \, (20-14)_{10}=6_{10}=20_3$, so $p(x)=14+2x+2x^2+2x^3+x^5$ gives $p(\sqrt3)=20+17\sqrt3, p(2)=74$.

Comment: Uff, I have made a minute mistake in writing up the question, 0≤a0≤3. Very very sorry guys for the mistake

Comment: No worries. That is why I asked.